Upgraded PHPMailer Fails
My code has been working very well since 2011, but this year, it notified me that I needed to upgrade the PHPMailer, and after upgrading, the code fails...
Here is the code that seems to be failing:
// Set up new PHPmailer connection and set to SMTP version

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->isSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only, 0 = off
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tis';
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->AddAddress($recipAddr);


// Set up user information and server information

    $mail->Username = "Todd.Greeno@gmail.com";

// Using an App PW for gMail
    $mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
//  $mail->SetFrom = "Todd.Greeno@gmail.com";
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;
    $mail->Body = $msg;


    echo "Sending message";


//  Send message to current recipient

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            $ErrorTrap .= "<tr><td nowrap>NOT Sent: </td><td nowrap>" . $RecipientName . "</td><td nowrap>" . $recipientAddress . "</td></tr>" . $eol;
            $Failed = $Failed + 1 ;

    } else {
//      echo "Message has been sent ";
            $ResultMsg .= "<tr><td align=center>" . $CurrPriority . "</td><td nowrap>Sent to: </td><td nowrap>" . $RecipientName . "</td><td nowrap>" . $recipientAddress . "</td></tr>" . $eol;
            $Counter = $Counter + 1;
            $uQuery="UPDATE Recipients SET DateSent=CURDATE(), Priority=$SentPriority WHERE EmailAddress='$recipientAddress'";
            mysqli_query($link, $uQuery);
//        sleep(8);
      }
  }

...and here is the resulting error:
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
I'm not sure how to correct this, and any help would be appreciated.
My profound thanks in advance!

What happened when you followed the link to the troubleshooting guide and did what it said?

Or perhaps followed the gmail example provided with PHPMailer? You have some straightforward mistakes in your code, so it's not going to work regardless of version, but that has nothing to do with PHPMailer itself. You also have no error checking anywhere, so you won't know what fails, and you've turned debug output off, so that won't show you anything either. All of this is covered in the docs and examples, so please look at them.
